# Find all words by pattern {{*}}

Tags: php

I have a problem for getting keywords in the text. I have text similar this

```
$str = '<?php {{namespace}} 
{{use}} 
{{abstract}} class {{pattern}} {{parent}} {{interface}}
{
    {{trait}}    
    {{property}}    
    {{method}}
}';
```

And I wont to get all words inside `{{..}}`. How can i do it?
Thanks/

Comment: Change the regexp from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48795341/7663972).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex like this one: `preg_match_all("/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/", $str, $matches);`

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/XyG224/1

Comment: result is preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add / at the beginning and the end of pattern. I've update my example

Comment: only one small improve can you do it??

Comment: 0 => "namespace"
    1 => "use"
    2 => "abstract}} class {{pattern}} {{parent}} {{implements"
    3 => "trait"
    4 => "constant"
    5 => "property"
    6 => "method"

Comment: only `"abstract}} class {{pattern}} {{parent}} {{implements"` this part is incorrect